# How to get div text by id with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, getelementbyid

I am trying to get a book's description text from its amazon [webpage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393337170). I get the book's image and title and price fine by using `driver.find_element_by_id`, but when it comes to the description which is in a `div` with `id="iframeContent"`, it doesn't work. Why? I have also tried `WebDriverWait` but no luck.

I use the following code:

```
def get_product_description(self, url):
    """Returns the product description of the Amazon URL."""
    self.driver.get(url)
    try:
        product_desc = self.driver.find_element_by_id("iframeContent")
    except:
        pass

    if product_desc is None:
        product_desc = "Not available"
    return product_desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use text method from selenium.

```
try:
    product_desc = self.driver.find_element_by_id("iframeContent").text
    print(product_desc)
except:
    pass
```

**Update 1:**

There's a iframe involved so you need to change the focus of webdriver to iframe first

```
iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_id("bookDesc_iframe")
self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
product_desc = self.driver.find_element_by_id("iframeContent").text
print(product_desc)
```

Now you can access every element which is inside bookDesc_iframe iframe, but the elements which are outside this frame you need to set the webdriver focus to default first, something like this below :

```
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. The problem is it doesnt find the id iframeContent, let alone its text.

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to use switch_to.frame to switch to iframe in order to proceed further otherwise you will get noSuchElement exception

Answer (score 1):

Since that element is inside the `iframe` you have to switch to that `iframe` in order to access elements inside the `iframe`.
So first you have to locate the `iframe`

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("bookDesc_iframe")
```

then switch to it with

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Now you can access the element located by the `div#iframeContent` `css_selector`
And finally you should get out from the `iframe` to the default content with

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Credits to the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834542/3485434)